# How do I find the smallest enclosing circle around uniform circles?

Tags: circles

Given N amount of uniform circles of radius R, how do I find the radius of the smallest enclosing circle around the uniform circles?

Comment: By "uniform circle" do you mean  these circles are in circular motion around a center and these circles are all R from the center?  Or that all of these circles are in motion of different distances but all the uniform circles are radius R?  Or something else?

Comment: These circles all have the same radius. They can be arranged in any pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is in the plane.
You want to take the [minimum enclosing circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) of the centres of your $N$ circles and add 
$R$ to its radius.  Finding the minimum enclosing circle is not simple, but according to that Wikipedia page it can be done in time linear in $N$.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I don't understand the algorithm to do so though.